# Can I sync an iPodTouch with both a Mac and Ubuntu?

Tags: sync, ipod

I've seen a whole bunch of posts on iTunes replacements for Ubuntu, and how to sync your iPodTouch with Banshee, Rhythmbox, etc. But here's my question: can you sync an iPod with both a Mac and an Ubuntu machine? I know if you try to sync a single iPod with iTunes on 2 different computers it won't let you. But I'm not trying to sync with iTunes on both computers.

Background: I use a Mac at work and Ubuntu at home. I'd like both computers to contain all of my music. I don't want to manually copy files by mounting the iPod as a disk. Is this possible? I'm fine with somehow declaring one machine as the "master" library (i.e. doing all downloads/purchases/deletes on that machine, then syncing the iPod to it and then syncing the second computer to the iPod.)

I'm using: iPodTouch 4g, Mac OSX (10.6.7 Snow Leopard), Ubuntu Maverick

Comment: My vote would be for yes but I am not 100% certain

Answer (score 1):

```
Can you sync an iPod with both a Mac and an Ubuntu machine?
```

If you want to know whether you can or not, then my answer is YES, you can sync with bot computers. BUT, what if you download, for example, a song on your Ubuntu PC, use Banshee (or any other) to sync it with your iPod, and then connect it to your MAC, using iTunes?

If you do this, the downloaded song will be deleted, as iTunes copies the database on the hard drive to the iPod, and not backwards.
To be able to do this, you would need to copy the downloaded dong using YamiPod (or any other) to your PC, add it to iTunes, and sync it again.

```
I don't want to manually copy files by mounting the iPod as a disk. 
Is this possible?
```

My recommendation is to use the Mac PC to manage your iPod, and if you want to make any changes with the Ubuntu PC do as I explained above.
But, if you want to use your Ubuntu PC to manage it, there is no problem (talking only about multimedia files, songs, video and photos. Syncing the calendar, or contacts requires more work) you can use it (As a mater of fact, I do).

But remember to disable the option that opens iTunes when you connect the iPod, or the one that automatically syncs it when iTunes is opened and the iPod is connected, this way you won't have any problems

Comment: "BUT, what if you download, for example, a song on your Ubuntu PC, use Banshee (or any other) to sync it with your iPod, and then connect it to your MAC, using iTunes?" As I said in the OP, I'm fine with making all changes on only one computer. So I should theoretically be able to download a song in iTunes on my mac, sync the iPod with iTunes, then sync Banshee with the iPod to get the new song into Banshee? Really, what I'm looking for is a way to do a one-way update of Banshee, not really a sync.

Comment: @emmys: If what you are looking is that, then you can do it. Banshee is much more flexible than iTunes, you can even play the files stored on your iPod without copying them to your PC (You can copy them if you want, it's a really easy process). iTunes fails at this, as it's much more restrictive.

Comment: This seems to be for you EmmyS, but @sebikul seems to be too shy to tell you: If you want to get full access to your iPod I would recommend using YamiPod. It is updated and supports the latest models, as in this case the iPodTouch 4g. But it's still a really good software, the best thing is that it acts as a file explorer, which makes it very easy to use. – @sebikul

Comment: @geppettvs-dconstanzo: I didn't understand your last comment, I posted that comment on your answer, why are you repeating what I said if it's already on the answer? Besides, the last part of my comment refers to the software you talked about on your answer, and without it, it seems out of context.

Comment: @geppettvs-dconstanzo: I'm going to give you exactly the same response here as I did to the answer you apparently deleted - I'm not looking for a file browser; I don't want to perform manual file operations like copy/paste, or dragging. I want automatic syncing/updating.